# Will half-inch ultralight drywall at 24 inch centers sag?

Tags: drywall

I am finishing my attic and planning to use 1/2 inch ultralight drywall. I am wondering if at 24 inch centers will the drywall sag.  Would furring strips at 16 inches on center work better?

[image]

Comment: Will there be weight on the drywall, or is in insulation supported by some other means above the drywall? I would guess those are baffles and there *will* be insulation on it?

Comment: Yes.... and yes.

Comment: There will be R21 insulation with a vapor barrier above the drywall on the sloped parts of the wall.  Thicker insulation on the ceiling and walls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

24" truss/joist spacing is standard across the home industry even in cold climate zones. As long as your 1/2" drywall is "no sag" it'll be fine, barring excessive moisture (during or after the finishing process). I'm not sure anything called "ultralight" will also be "no sag", though.

Basically, read the manual. Any such product has a clear spec sheet. Here's the answer for [USG Sheetrock™ UltraLight](https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/sheetrock-gypsum-panels-installation-guide-en-J371.pdf) in 1/2". I interpret it to mean that 24" spacing is ok.

[image]